# How to show red circle with exclamation in NSTextField when the value is not valid?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I would like to show red circle with exclamation in the text field when the filled value is incorrect (like XCode):

[image: xcode sample]

Do you know if there is an out of the box solution or I have to override the drawRect method ?
A sample of code is welcome :)

Comment: You could always just add it as a subview when a delegate method is called and the input turns out to be incorrect, if all else fails.

Comment: Thanks, It's a good idea. I can use constraints to align my subview.